# Updating and filtering a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I have been making a trading platform for crypto currency trading. I have created a table to show all coin pair on a exchange. I update this table every 5 seconds with data that i get from a exchange. I also want to filter the table through an input (if user types in BTC, there will only be BTC pair listed in the table).

In general this works, but if I want to filter the table, everytime the table updates itself some other pairs that are supposed to be filtered show up for 2-3 seconds and then disappear. It often happens that pairs, that are supposed to be shown, also dissapear for those 2-3 seconds.

First I create the table

```
createMainTable: function () {
    var marketLen, column, row;
    bittrex.getmarketsummaries(function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        marketLen = data.result.length;
        var table = document.getElementById("mainTableBody");
        for (i = 0; i < marketLen; i++) {
            row = table.insertRow(i);
            row.id = data.result[i].MarketName;
            row.addEventListener('click', function () {
                testFun();
            })
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                column = row.insertCell(j);
                column.className = "col" + j;

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Then I pass in data from the exchange every 5 seconds:

```
fillMainTable: function () {
    var marketName, marketVolume, marketChange, market, marketName_2, lastPrice;
    bittrex.getmarketsummaries(function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        }
        symbolNav = document.getElementById("coin-name").innerHTML;
        market = data.result
        for (i = 0; i < market.length; i++) {
            marketName = market[i].MarketName;
            marketVolume = market[i].BaseVolume.toFixed(2);
            marketChange = (market[i].Last / market[i].PrevDay * 100 - 100);
            marketChange = marketChange.toFixed(1);
            lastPrice = market[i].Last.toFixed(8);

            if (marketChange > 0) {
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 2).style.color = "#28a745";
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 2).innerHTML = marketChange + "&#11014;";
            }
            if (marketChange < 0) {
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 2).style.color = "#dc3545";
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 2).innerHTML = marketChange + "&#11015;";
            }
            if (marketChange == 0) {
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 2).style.color = "black";
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 2).innerHTML = marketChange + "&#9679;";
            }


            if (marketName[0] === 'B') {
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 1).innerHTML = marketVolume + ' BTC';
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 3).innerHTML = lastPrice + ' BTC';
            }
            if (marketName[0] === 'E') {

                document.getElementById("col" + i + 1).innerHTML = marketVolume + ' ETH';
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 3).innerHTML = lastPrice + ' ETH';
            }
            if (marketName[0] === 'U') {
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 1).innerHTML = marketVolume + ' USDT';
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 3).innerHTML = lastPrice + ' USDT';
            }


            if (marketName[0] === 'B') {
                marketName_2 = marketName.slice(4) + "-BTC"
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 0).innerHTML = marketName_2;
            }
            if (marketName[0] === 'E') {
                marketName_2 = marketName.slice(4) + "-ETH"
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 0).innerHTML = marketName_2;
            }
            if (marketName[0] === 'U') {
                marketName_2 = marketName.slice(5) + "-USDT"
                document.getElementById("col" + i + 0).innerHTML = marketName_2;
            }
        }
        market = null;
    });
}
```

Table headers are created in html file:

```
 <table id="mainTable" class="table">
            <tr>
                <thead>
                    <th>Coin</th>
                    <th>Vol</th>
                    <th>% Change</th>
                    <th>Last price</th>
                </thead>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="mainTableBody">
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The function for filtering is below. Inputs in html has id tag of "tableFilter".

```
function filterTable() {
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
            input = document.getElementById("tableFilter");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) {
                    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Why not use JQuery based DataTables (https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) that will do the above with minimal configuration?

Comment: Thank you. Will check it out. I am quite new to web development.